# mi login no funciona

Tags: html, python, django

tengo un problema con mi login, al momento de poner el usuario y la contraseña e intentar ingresar no sucede nada,no me redirige a menu ni tampoco me muestra el mensaje de username incorrecto, en mi terminal tampoco detecta ningun error, se que tal vez sean las urls.py pero no estoy segura, tampoco se que pueda ser reamente , espero me puedan ayudar aun estoy estudiando, gracias!

https://github.com/elianaji/webcomfenalco.git

Comment: Por favor, en vez de enlazarnos a tu repositorio edita tu pregunta para incluir en ella un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Si haz copiado un login predeterminado en internet, no creo que se problema de código. Si dice que no hay problemas con el url, te creo también. Entonces te diría que primero pruebes generar un super usuario para Django y poder ingresar. En el caso de que ingrese, otro problema con los usuarios que estás manejando.

Escribe:
python manage.py createsuperuser
y pulsa enter

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta. Por favor lee [answer] y haz el [tour]